# Problem with Memory allocation in Visual Studio Code and Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read a .csv using the Python plugin (ms-python.python) that includes ability to read Jupyter Notebooks files) for Visual Studio Code.

The problem is that the file, that is 200 MB, rises a memory allocation error. Is there any setting to increase the amount of memory that Visual Studio Code can manage?

`data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")`

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 218. MiB for an array with shape (15, 1908333) and data type float64`

I know for sure that I have at least 200 MB of RAM available when reading the file.

Comment: Split csv as two df.